# building and loading local docker images in minikube from jenkins pipeline fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, kubectl, minikube

When I try to build or load local docker images in minikube from within a jenkins pipeline the images cannot be found. The build or load process takes some time as usual but there are no images found in minikube.

My setup is a standalone jenkins installation (no docker, no k8s) on the same host along with a minikube instance (running with docker driver) on Ubuntu 22.04. Jenkins is connected to the minikube using the Kubernetes jenkins plugin. Connection is working fine, all commands can be excuted from the jenkins pipeline (ex. kubectl get all) without problems.

When I try to build an image using
`minikube image build -t name/name -f ./Dockerfile .`
it takes some time (as usual), but no image can be found.
`minikube image list --format table`
says

```
|-------|-----|----------|------|
| Image | Tag | Image ID | Size |
|-------|-----|----------|------|
|-------|-----|----------|------|
```

When I try to load a local image using
`minikube image load name/name`
it also takes some time (as usual), but also no image can be found.
`minikube image list --format table`
says

```
|-------|-----|----------|------|
| Image | Tag | Image ID | Size |
|-------|-----|----------|------|
|-------|-----|----------|------|
```

When I run the commands manually from the console (not from within the jenkins pipeline) it all works fine.

Where can I find the built/loaded images?